# height auto on parent and overflow-y scroll on child, div not resizing. (popup)

Tags: jquery, html, ios, css

I have the following code. Its purpose is to display a popup to the user.

As you can see in the screenshot, login window appears with blank space after it. The register works and has `y-scrolling` avaliable. When I change `.contentWindowContainer` css to `height:auto;` the login box displays correctly, but the register form looses its scroll ability. screenshot showing two modals

My question is how can I preserve the functionality of scrolling the register whilst preventing the signin box from having white space underneith?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LVQeGp

if you change the `.contentWindow` `height` property from `auto` to `100%` you should see the error.

[image]
Thanks, Adam

Comment: The CodePen doesn't look like your screenshot or have the problem you're presenting

Comment: if you change the  `.contentWindow` height property from `auto` to `100%` you should see what I mean. I havent included the styles from the site as not required for the example. Thanks for taking a look!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you move your `overflow-y: scroll` from `.contentWindowContainer` to `.contentWindow` then the whole things works fine with `height: auto`.  It did add an extra scroll bar to the side, so I dug through and removed all the places you had added it in with jquery.  If any of those were important (I didn't know about the one removing `overflow-y`, but I got rid of it too) then I'm not sure how to get rid of the extra scroll bar.  Other than that it seems to work fine.  Here's the [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VLQQWx).

Hopefully that doesn't break any other relevant code, but without seeing the rest of it, there's not much else to work with.

Comment: Thank you so much mate this is great. There was some strange behaviour on safari/ios when toggling between the two windows, but have resolved that with a couple of bits of jquery. Your a star!